# Xpath how find elements between two siblings where one haven't unique attributes

Tags: xpath

I need to find the siblings `XCUIElementTypeCell` between the first sibling `XCUIElementTypeOther` that has the given text, and the second sibling `XCUIElementTypeOther`, which also has text (see on picture), but at the time of the search we do not know this text (so we assume that it does not have unique attributes). I tried to write something like this:

```
//XCUIElementTypeCell/XCUIElementTypeStaticText[preceding::XCUIElementTypeOther[./XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name="' + text + '"]]][following::XCUIElementTypeOther[./XCUIElementTypeStaticText][1]]
```

but it does not work (looks for all siblings `XCUIElementTypeCell` after the first one). I can not figure out how to define in xpath. 
I tried to find an answer among the questions already asked, but the attempt failed.

[image: source]

Comment: Thank you all so much, guys! All your expressions work for me. I mark **gtoso**'s answer as a solution, because he was the first to respond (if I don't mistake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expression should work

```
//XCUIElementTypeOther[XCUIElementTypeStaticText/@name = 'your text here']/following-sibling::XCUIElementTypeOther[1]/preceding-sibling::XCUIElementTypeCell
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just test the first `preceding-sibling::XCUIElementTypeOther` with a child `XCUIElementTypeStaticText` that has an attribute `name` with the value of your `text` variable...

```
//XCUIElementTypeCell[preceding-sibling::XCUIElementTypeOther[1][XCUIElementTypeStaticText/@name="' + text + '"]]
```

For example with this input...

```
<doc>
    <XCUIElementTypeCell>1</XCUIElementTypeCell>
    <XCUIElementTypeCell>2</XCUIElementTypeCell>
    <XCUIElementTypeCell>3</XCUIElementTypeCell>
    <XCUIElementTypeOther>
        <XCUIElementTypeStaticText name="not me"/>
    </XCUIElementTypeOther>
    <XCUIElementTypeCell>4</XCUIElementTypeCell>
    <XCUIElementTypeCell>5</XCUIElementTypeCell>
    <XCUIElementTypeCell>6</XCUIElementTypeCell>
    <XCUIElementTypeCell>7</XCUIElementTypeCell>
    <XCUIElementTypeOther>
        <XCUIElementTypeStaticText name="pick me"/>
    </XCUIElementTypeOther>
    <XCUIElementTypeCell>8</XCUIElementTypeCell>
    <XCUIElementTypeCell>9</XCUIElementTypeCell>
    <XCUIElementTypeCell>10</XCUIElementTypeCell>
    <XCUIElementTypeCell>11</XCUIElementTypeCell>
    <XCUIElementTypeOther>
        <XCUIElementTypeStaticText name="not me"/>
    </XCUIElementTypeOther>
    <XCUIElementTypeCell>12</XCUIElementTypeCell>
    <XCUIElementTypeCell>13</XCUIElementTypeCell>
    <XCUIElementTypeCell>14</XCUIElementTypeCell>
    <XCUIElementTypeCell>15</XCUIElementTypeCell>
</doc>
```

With this XPath...

```
//XCUIElementTypeCell[preceding-sibling::XCUIElementTypeOther[1][XCUIElementTypeStaticText/@name="pick me"]]
```

The selected `XCUIElementTypeCell` elements would be...

```
<XCUIElementTypeCell>8</XCUIElementTypeCell>
<XCUIElementTypeCell>9</XCUIElementTypeCell>
<XCUIElementTypeCell>10</XCUIElementTypeCell>
<XCUIElementTypeCell>11</XCUIElementTypeCell>
```